# Next.js project doesn't start

Tags: npm, next.js

I am trying to start my Next.js project, but getting an error:

```
$ npm run start

> sanad-blog@0.1.0 start
> next start

- ready started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sanad\OneDrive\Desktop\cms-blog\sanad-blog\.next\BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\sanad\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\cms-blog\\sanad-blog\\.next\\BUILD_ID'
}
```

Can someone guide what went wrong? I've cleared the cache and reinstalled npm but still it's not working.

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "sanad-blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.17",
    "graphql": "^16.8.0",
    "graphql-request": "^6.1.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^4.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "^13.4.17",
    "postcss": "8.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.4",
    "sass": "^1.65.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are running the npm start that is why is giving you the ENOET error you can run npm start after you run npm run build but in your case use npm run dev to start the application

Answer (score 3):

Use `npm run dev` and not `npm run start`. The start is for production, which works after a `npm run build`.

As you have in your `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your project in a folder where you don't use space and uppercase letters. So, like `c:\projects\sanad-blog`

Nexj.js is very picky on this, from my experience.