# Running next start fails with Error No Entry

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

Next start command is failing with error no entry.

My next config looks like this.

Typically, I use `npm run dev` and `npm run build`:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    distDir: 'dist',
    images: {
        unoptimized: true
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Also, running just 'start' as package JSON is '`next start`' asks for a filepath.

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\source\repos\mysite\MySite\dist\BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\me\\source\\repos\\mysite\\MySite\\dist\\BUILD_ID'
}
```

When running `npm run build`, I get some red on some of the files, not sure if this is related to my static chunk error post as well.

[image]

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76922704/next-js-project-doesnt-start.

Comment: same issue when running 'npm run build' then 'next start'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code. you need to comment out `output: 'export'`. if I build the same settings as yours:

[image]

if you look at the dist folder, this is not a proper build. look at the output error on terminal. If you use this setting:

```
const nextConfig = {
  //   output: "export",
  distDir: "dist",
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
};
```

you get a proper build folder and `npm run start` works

[image]

Comment: This was my hunch, I used output: 'export' because it was the only way to get past a 403 on the server side and is working on the server but with obvious issues on refresh or some material components maybe. If I comment that out, I'll get a 403 forbidden nginx issue on the deployed url, but I will continue troubleshooting down that path, my guess is it's a nginx config thing beyond this. Thank you for your reply I'll accept when I can gather a bit more info.

Comment: I am not worried about getting accepted or not. but when you post a question, you should explain everything in detail.  you did not mention about nginx on the post. if you update your question, you might have your problem solved